# DAYOFWEEK e IF en diferentes fechas

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla tipo así:

```
| id | id_cliente | fecha         | id_admin
|:--------|:----:| --------------:|
| 1       | 1    |'2021-10-03'    | 1
| 2       | 2    |'2021-10-04'    | 2
```

Y un SELECT así:

```
SELECT 
   IF( 
     (DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 1 OR DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 7), COUNT(*)*2, COUNT(*)
) as num 
FROM tabla 
GROUP BY id_admin
```

Lo que quiero es que los registros donde la fecha sea Sábado o Domingo valen x2 y de lunes a viernes x1, sin embargo, solamente hace el x2 en la última fecha del admin, y no por cada una, es decir, si la la fecha del último registro del admin es domingo, todos valen x2 etc.

¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Comment: COUNT es una función de agregación, así que estás contando toda la tabla, agrupada por id_admin y le pones el conteo completo o el conteo completo *2 cada vez. Seguro que es eso lo que deseas?

Comment: Me parece que lo que necesitas aquí es SUM()  no COUNT(*)

Comment: @Alfabravo Con el COUNT(*) y el GROUP BY lo que hace es contar el número de filas que tiene cada id_admin, quiero que las filas que sean sabado o domingo, cuenten x2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que los sábados y domingos **sumen `+2`** y el resto de días **sumen `+1`**, basta con esto:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 1 OR DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 7 
          THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
       ) AS num
FROM tabla 
GROUP BY id_admin
```

Comment: Funciona! 
No había caído, muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servidor, @Exale. Saludos.